# Import XSD to OpenAPI

Tags: json, xsd, openapi

I have some model definition inside a XSD file and I need to reference these models from an OpenApi definition. Manually remodeling is no option since the file is too large, and I need to put it into a build system, so that if the XSD is changed, I can regenerate the models/schemas for OpenApi.

What I tried and what nearly worked is using [xsd2json](https://github.com/fnogatz/xsd2json) and then converting it with the node module [json-schema-to-openapi](https://github.com/wework/json-schema-to-openapi-schema). However `xsd2json` is dropping some of the `complexElement` models. For example `"$ref": "#/definitions/tns:ContentNode"` is used inside of one model as the child type but there is no definition for `ContentNode` in the schema, where when I look into the XSD, there is a `complexElement` definition for `ContentNode`.

Another approach which I haven't tried yet but seems a bit excessive to me is using xjb to generate Java models from the XSD and then using JacksonSchema to generate the json schema.

Is there any established library or way, to use XSD in OpenApi?

Comment: xsd2json seems to have some quirks; e.g. it expects that the targetNamespaces is equal to the default namespace (`<xs:schema targetNamspace="http://whatnot/" xmlns="http://whatnot/" xmlns:xs=...>`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I ended up implementing the second approach using jaxb to convert the XSD to java models and then using Jackson to write the schemas to files.

Gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
}

group 'foo'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.module', name: 'jackson-module-jsonSchema', version: '2.9.8'
}

configurations {
    jaxb
}

dependencies {
    jaxb (
            'com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-xjc:2.2.7',
            'com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:2.2.7'
    )
}

application {
    mainClassName = 'foo.bar.Main'
}

task runConverter(type: JavaExec, group: 'application') {
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath

    main = 'foo.bar.Main'
}

task jaxb {
    System.setProperty('javax.xml.accessExternalSchema', 'all')
    def jaxbTargetDir = file("src/main/java")

    doLast {
        jaxbTargetDir.mkdirs()

        ant.taskdef(
                name: 'xjc',
                classname: 'com.sun.tools.xjc.XJCTask',
                classpath: configurations.jaxb.asPath
        )
        ant.jaxbTargetDir = jaxbTargetDir

        ant.xjc(
                destdir: '${jaxbTargetDir}',
                package: 'foo.bar.model',
                schema: 'src/main/resources/crs.xsd'
        )
    }
}

compileJava.dependsOn jaxb
```

With a converter main class, that does something along the lines of:

```
package foo.bar;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.jsonSchema.JsonSchema;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.jsonSchema.JsonSchemaGenerator;
import foo.bar.model.Documents;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        JsonSchemaGenerator schemaGen = new JsonSchemaGenerator(mapper);
        try {
            JsonSchema schema = schemaGen.generateSchema(Documents.class);
            System.out.print(mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(schema));
        } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

It is still not perfect though,... this would need to iterate over all the model classes and generate a file with the schema. Also it doesn't use references, if a class has a member of another class, the schema is printed inline instead of referencing. This requires a bit more customization with the `SchemaFactoryWrapper` but can be done.

Comment: this way you can't port type descriptions

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is that you are applying inference tooling over a multi-step conversion. As you have found, inference tooling is inherently fussy and will not work in all situations. It's kind of like playing [Chinese whispers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_whispers) - every step of the chain is potentially lossy, so what you get out the other end may be garbled.

Based on the alternative approach you suggest, I would suggest a similar solution:

OpenAPI is, rather obviously, an API definition standard. It should be possible for you to take a code first approach, composing your API operations in code and exposing the types generated from XJB. Then you can use [Apiee](https://github.com/phillip-kruger/apiee) and its annotations to generate the OpenAPI definition. This assumes you are using [JAX-RS](https://github.com/jax-rs) for your API.

This is still a two-step process, but one with a higher chance of success. The benefit here is that your first step, inferring your XSD types into java types, will hopefully have very little (if any) impact on the code which defines your API operations. Although there will still be a manual step (updating the models) the OpenAPI definition will update automatically once the code has been rebuilt.

Comment: The loss already in the first step of the chain, so this is atm. not a problem of using multiple steps. In this case we use OpenApi to describe a legacy API that is already in place. It is not written in Java. The API operation have already been described in an OpenApi yaml. The returned models are complex though but we have the XSD. We use OpenApi-generator to generate API clients for other projects, so we need the OpenApi yaml to reference the models, else the models will not be generated for other api clients. We are not able to add anything to the described API.