# Import schema from XSD to OpenAPI/swagger YAML

Tags: xsd, swagger, openapi

I have a schema definition in a XSD file which is provided by ISO20022. This schema will need to be used in a swagger/openAPI definition (in yaml format). Since the XSD file has about 1000 lines, manual work is impracticable. [This old thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56018335/import-xsd-to-openapi/67840275#67840275) mention some solution, but it is not straightforward.

Does anyone know any tool which provides an easy way to import the schema definitions from a XSD file into a swagger/openAPI yaml file?

Answer (score 3):

You could try xsd2json from the npm module jgexml. It was written to do precisely this for a large API specified in XSD.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I need the final data definition in swagger/openAPI yaml format, not in JSON.

Comment: OpenAPI uses JSON Schema to define the data models of requestBodies and responses. So you would wrap the generated JSON Schema in OpenAPI boilerplate. An XSD is never going to be able to define the other parts of OpenAPI like paths, headers, parameters etc etc.

Comment: OAS should not make its own schema definition language. it broke SRP principle.

Answer (score 1):

I could not escape from manual work in this task. What I've done was using "xsd2json" to convert the XSD schema to JSON. Then, I used the website [www.json2yaml.com](https://www.json2yaml.com/) to get it as YAML. Afterwards, I created a swagger file myself, then merged the YAML file into it.
Thanks for your responses!